# Microsoft Azure Service Bus Timeout Exceptions

Tags: c#, azure, timeout, azureservicebus

We have an application that runs on the Microsoft Azure cloud platform. The communication between some components is made using Service Bus. Everything was working fine, until recently we started to get the following type of timeout exceptions:

When calling `QueueClient x.Send(...)`

> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory `1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.b__4(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)

When calling `NamespaceManager x.GetQueue(...)`

> PROGRESS queue processing failed. System.TimeoutException: The request
>   has timed out after 60000 milliseconds. The successful completion of
>   the request cannot be determined. Additional queries should be made to
>   determine whether or not the operation has succeeded.
>   TrackingId:bdffb6bd-5367-4573-aaa3-8ea9a03f5a2b,TimeStamp:5/28/2015
>   8:39:46 AM ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The
>   request was canceled.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.GetAsyncResult`1.b__49(GetAsyncResult`1
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)

When calling `NamespaceManager x.SubscriptionExists(...)`

> Exception doing periodic work: System.TimeoutException: The request
>   has timed out after 00:10:00 milliseconds. The successful completion
>   of the request cannot be determined. Additional queries should be made
>   to determine whether or not the operation has succeeded. Server stack
>   trace:  Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.OnEndSubscriptionExists(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(String
>   topicPath, String name)    ...

When calling `QueueClient x.Receive(...)`

> PROGRESS queue processing failed.
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: Error
>   during communication with Service Bus. Check the connection
>   information, then retry. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: Internal
>   Server Error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this
>   might be caused by a premature session shutdown.
>   TrackingId:04ba0220-0350-4806-9c65-c2bba9671054, Timestamp:28.05.2015
>   13:00:55 Server stack trace: Exception rethrown at [0]:    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception
>   exception)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.b__4(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)   ….

The exceptions are clearly related to ServiceBus and they are non-deterministic. The functions throwing them, e.g., `Send`, `GetQueue`, `SubscriptionExists`, are called no more than 100-120 times per minute. We changed nothing in the code and increasing the timeout values (even to ridiculously high values, like 10min) did not help. Also, we do not believe it is some network related problem (on our side) since the same error occur when the application is run from different places.

Has anyone else encountered recently these kind of exceptions? Is there a problem on the side of Microsoft or we are missing something?

Comment: If your having similar tiumeout problems also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224200/azure-service-bus-topic-timeout-exception/38847121#38847121

Answer (score 3):

A few weeks back we had sudden and unexplainable timing issues crop up with our Service Bus app that has been in production for many months. Ours continued to work but every few calls would take 10+ seconds when they are normally 100-200 millisconds. This went on for a couple weeks and I spent most of that trying to figure out what was going on and never did as the problem suddenly vanished.

We did learn that new Service Bus namespaces we created in the same and other data centers for testing while the problem was occurring did not exhibit the same issue. The Service Bus group offered no help and would only say response times are not guaranteed only the SLA is.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when my running code started to generate Timeout exception. Upon research found that firewall blocked the port used for communication. However, port 80 and 443 were still open. So adding following line of code worked for me:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Https;
```